# Can a gdb backtrace somehow omit the argument values?

Tags: gdb

I'm working on some modifications to DynamoRIO, which uses `byte*` for pointers into the code cache. When I'm debugging in gdb, the `backtrace` command thinks every `byte*` is null terminated, so it prints this massive spew of byte values all over the backtrace. I need a way to either:

1. Turn off the display of arguments in the backtrace, or
2. Change the way gdb prints a `byte*` (preferably just the pointer value as a hex number)

Comment: Reducing the array size with `set print elements 10` seems to be the easiest thing. There's never enough space in a backtrace for the default 200 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use **"set print frame-arguments none"** to turn off display of arguments in backtraces. See [GDB Manual: Print Settings](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html#Print-Settings).
2. You can also [write a pretty printer in Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html) and register it with GDB to change how `byte *` are displayed.